# Convert facebook date to local time zone

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

Facebook returns this date

```
2010-12-16T14:39:30+0000
```

However, I noticed that it's 5 hours ahead of my local time. It should be:

```
2010-12-16T09:39:30+0000
```

<strike>How can I convert this to local time in javascript?</strike>

**Edit**

After seeing some responses, I feel I should define what I'm searching for more clearly. How would I be able to determine the user's local time zone to format the date?

Comment: The '+0000' is the time zone. If you're on PST that part would be '-0500'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the function to parse ISO8601 dates in Javascript, it also handles time offset correctly:
http://delete.me.uk/2005/03/iso8601.html

Answer (score 4):

This might help you:

taken from [Convert the local time to another time zone with this JavaScript](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6016329.html)

```
// function to calculate local time
// in a different city
// given the city's UTC offset
function calcTime(city, offset) {

    // create Date object for current location
    d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset 
    // get UTC time in msec
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();

}

// get Bombay time
alert(calcTime('Bombay', '+5.5'));

// get Singapore time
alert(calcTime('Singapore', '+8'));

// get London time
alert(calcTime('London', '+1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in Javascript

```
function timeStuff(time) {
      var date = new Date(time);
      date.setHours(date.getHours() - (date1.getTimezoneOffset()/60));  //for the timezone diff
      return date;
}
```